# Jenkins pipeline (parallel && dynamically)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## Question

I have simple parallel pipeline (see code) which I use together with Jenkins 2.89.2. Additionally I use parameters and now want to be able to in-/decrease the number of deployVM A..Z stages automatically by providing the parameter before job execution.

How can I dynamically build my pipeline by providing a parameter?

Researched so far:

- [Jenkins pipeline script created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082261/jenkins-pipeline-script-created-dynamically) - Not getting this to work with my Jenkins version
- [Can I create dynamically stages in a Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline) - Not working either

## Code

The pseudo code of what I want - dynamic generation:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'countTotal', defaultValue: '3')
    }

    stages {

       stage('deployVM') {

        def list = [:]
        for(int i = 0; i < countTotal.toInteger; i++) {
            list += stage("deployVM ${i}") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh "echo p1; sleep 12s; echo phase${i}"
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        failFast true
        parallel list
       }

   }

}
```

The code I have so far - executes parallel but is static:

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    stages {

       stage('deployVM') {
        failFast true
        parallel {
            stage('deployVM A') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh "echo p1; sleep 12s; echo phase1"
                    }

                }
            }
            stage('deployVM B') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh "echo p1; sleep 20s; echo phase2"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline), it's way more flexible.

Comment: I read the article but do not see how I could apply it here. Can you provide an example? The documentation is really sparse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although the question assumes using declarative pipeline I would suggest to use [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) because it's way more flexible.
Your task can be accomplished this way

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(name: 'countTotal', defaultValue: '3')
    ])
])

def stages = [failFast: true]
for (int i = 0; i < params.countTotal.toInteger(); i++) {
    def vmNumber = i //alias the loop variable to refer it in the closure
    stages["deployVM ${vmNumber}"] = {
        stage("deployVM ${vmNumber}") {
            sh "echo p1; sleep 12s; echo phase${vmNumber}"
        }
    }
}

node() {
    parallel stages
}
```

Also take a look at [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) which allows you to generate some scripted pipeline code.

Comment: could you help to take a look at my problems (as answer below cause one liner did not format well), thanks in advance :)

Comment: < def vmNumber = i //alias the loop variable to refer it in the closure > This is a nice trick. it helped me Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh man! I was struggling with the closure for hours.

Answer (score 2):

Using Declarative pipeline also you can achieve this.

Follow my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline/66438907#66438907)

In above link answer I have used `Var.collectEntries` but `map` also can be used.

Answer (score 1):

@Vitalii

I wrote similiar code piece, but unfoutunelty, all three element been loopped all shows the last one, not sure if it had something to do with groovy / jenkinsfile itself, that some clouse / reference went break with wrong usage

my purpose is to distribute tasks to specific work nodes

```
node_candicates = ["worker-1", "worder-2", "worker-3"]

def jobs = [:]
for (node_name in node_candidates){
    jobs["run on $node_name"] = {             // good
        stage("run on $node_name"){           // all show the third 
            node(node_name){                  // all show the third 
                print "on $node_name"
                sh "hostname"
            }
        }
    }
}    
parallel jobs
```

it went totally Ok if I expand / explain the loop, instead of loop over it, like

```
parallel worker_1: {
    stage("worker_1"){
        node("worker_1"){
            sh """hostname ; pwd """
            print "on worker_1"
        }
    }
},  worker_2: {
    stage("worker_2"){
        node("worker_2"){
            sh """hostname ; pwd """
            print "on worker_2"
        }
    }
},  worker_3: {
    stage("worker_3"){
        node("worker_3"){
            sh """hostname ; pwd """
            print "on worker_3"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This happens because all closures you created bound to the same variable  `node_name`. This is why a created `vmNumber` extra variable in my original answer. You can read more here http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/

Comment: Do you mind posting this as a separate question? Posting your question to an answer section breaks SO rules.

Comment: @viyalii, this is just what I worried, so in such functional / ml language, variables are not actually variable, thanks for the info and link, I should be able to finish my script, and I guess no bother to creat a separate thread? Just in case some other guy had similar issue could see this, and this could be closed?

Comment: And sure, I'll delete this and create another problem if you thought that way organized better and give you the link ?